# Как мне заменить объект под вторым индексом в этом списке?

Tags: python

2 случая есть. Первое, где решение всей задачи и все отлично. Второе, когда просто разбирался, как заменить в списке объект по индексу

```py
for n in range(10000):
    s = str(n)
    s = list(s)
    s[1] = "0"
    print(s)
```

вывод

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Исправьте ваш вопрос, удалив картинки и добавив код текстом. Для этого нажмите [edit] под самим вопросом

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Индексация списков питона начинается с нуля. Однозначные цифры превратятся в список из одного элемента с индексом `0`. Элемента с индексом `1` не будет для них. Поэтому ошибка и возникает.

Comment: у вас компьютер и вы не нашли ничего более умного, чем сделать скриншот?

Comment: @Zhihar все намного хуже. Это фотография!

Comment: Я вам поправил, в следующий раз буду безжалостно голосовать за закрытие

Answer (score 1):

На первой итерации у вас в переменной s хранится значение `"0"`.

в строке

```py
s = list(s)
```

вы получаете список с одним элементом и индексом 0.
То есть хранимое значение такое

```py
["0"]
```

Следовательно, когда вы в этой строке

```py
s[1] = "0"
```

пытаетесь сделать замену, у вас падает ошибка, что данного элемента не существует, что есть истина.

Если вы начнете ваш перебор с двузначного числа, например с 10, то вы не увидите данной ошибки

```py
for n in range(10, 10000):
    s = str(n)
    s = list(s)
    s[1] = "0"
    print(s)
```